# Passing sessions to iframe within same page

Tags: php, session, iframe, session-variables

I'm having problem when passing sessions to iframe.
This is the first page

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 

$_SESSION['views']="test";

?>
<html><head>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="/PHP/test.php" width="100%" height="100px" id="iframe2" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and iframe page

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
```

I always get empty array 
i don't know why.

Comment: do `var_dump(session_id())` in both scripts. If you get different ID values, then your session cookie isn't being set correctly and you're ending up with different sessions in the pages.

Comment: Yes i'm getting different id's. How can i solve it?

Comment: check your browser's cookie stash, you'll probably have two different session cookies (`PHPSESSID`?), with different directory restrictions. you'll have to fix up the session cookie settings in your php.ini to relax the directory stuff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path

Comment: What settings i should change?

Comment: I get only 1 PHPSESSID and it's the ID of the iframe page

Answer (score 0):

`$session_start();` can not be declared twince !

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['views']="test";

?>

<html><head>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="/PHP/test.php" width="100%" height="100px" id="iframe2" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

test.php /iframe

```
var_dump($_SESSION); 'OR
$views = $_SESSION['views'];
echo $views;
```